# Prove that $f$ has limit in $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a continuous function, that takes each value at most ten
times. Show that $f$ has a limit as $x \to \infty$.

It's easy to show that $$\forall y \ \exists u \ : \ (\forall x > u \ f(x) > y \text{ or }\forall x > u \ f(x) < y)$$

If for some $y$ we couldn't find $y'$ such that $\forall y' > y \ \exists u' : \forall x > u' f(x) < y'$, the limit is $=+\infty$ (or $-\infty$ in mirror situation).

But what I can do in other situations? How can we prove that limit exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try the contraposition. If $f$ does not have a limit for $x \to \infty$, then
$$ \varliminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) < \varlimsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) $$
Choose $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$ \varliminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) < a < b < \varlimsup_{x \to \infty} f(x)$$
As $b < \varlimsup f$, there is $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) > b$. As $a > \varliminf f$, we find $y_0 > x_0$ such that $f(y_0) < a$. By induction, we find sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ such that

1. $f(x_n) > b$, all $n \in \mathbb N$
2. $f(y_n) < a$, all $n \in \mathbb N$
3. $x_n < y_n < x_{n+1}$, all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Now let $m := \frac{a+b}2$. As $f(x_n)< a < m < b < f(y_n)$, by the intermediate value theorem there is $\xi_n \in (x_n, y_n)$ such that $f(\xi_n) = m$. Hence, $m$ is taken at infinitely many points.